# Full screen swing application on different resolutions

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen, resolution

I'm currently writing a desktopapplication using swing. My problem is that it is a fullscreen application that has to run on different computers with different screens and different resultions. Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?
I was also thinking I could resize every component on my screen using some sort of percentage and place them with an absolute positioning on the screen? I'm pretty sure this could/will work. I just don't konw if this is good coding...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By fullscreen do you mean you do not want the task bar to be visible?

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to achieve this using different LayoutManagers brought to you by the JVM. A good starting point should be [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

A very flexible and easy to use LayoutManager can be found in the JGoodies framework. Please have a look at [:: JGoodies Forms ::](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/index.html) and its [Whitepaper](http://www.jgoodies.com/articles/forms.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
```

or

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
gd.setFullScreenWindow(app);
```